# Can the solution of an equation be another equation

Tags: calculus

The solutions of an algebraic, transcendental, differential and etc. equation are numbers or functions. Just out of curiosity, can the solution be an equation?

Comment: You should look up 'functionals'

Comment: I realize this is contrary to Wikipedia's definition of equation, but I always take an equation to be a question, so the answer cannot be an equation. That said, it really depends on what you mean by words. "Equation" is not a term that is rigorously defined in mathematics, so it is hard to say what the answer would mean without a definition.